# IntelliJ does not detect cyclic dependencies between packages

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Given:

A.kt

```
package server.a

import server.b.B

class A(val b: B)
```

B.kt

```
package server.b

import server.a.A

class B(val a: A)
```

When I build the project and select *Main menu | Analyze | Analyze Cyclic Dependencies... | Analyze the whole project*, no cycles are shown.

[image]

Is this a bug? If not, what kind of cycles would IntelliJ detect? Or is this a restriction of the Community Edition?

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-192.6603.28, built on September 6, 2019

Comment: Please follow the issue created for your report at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33881

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Olga Klisho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10744483/)'s comment and linked [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33881), this is a Kotlin-specific bug.